# Interactive plot updated during sliding in R

Tags: r

I need an interactive plot with two sliders, and **I want the plot to be updated smoothly as I slide, without releasing mouse button.** Do you know of any other solution in R which is able to do that?

I found a nice library `manipulate` (see example below), but the plot is only updated after releasing mouse button, so I have to stop sliding to see updated plot (which makes the experience not smooth). I want the plot to be updated during sliding already.

```
library(manipulate)
manipulate(curve(amp*sin(freq*x), xlim = c(0,10), ylim =c(-1,1)), amp = slider(0.1,1), freq = slider(0.1,10))
```

[image]

PS: I am used to just base graphics library, so I prefer simple solutions using that; but if there's no other way, ggplot/lattice is good as well :-))

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate you were looking for a answer in base R, however shiny is typically a good choice for interactive plots in R.

The following code should achieve your desired output (and you do not have to release the mouse button for the plot to update):

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  # Sidebar with a slider input
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput(
        inputId = "amp",
        label = "Amp:",
        min = 0.1,
        max = 1,
        value = 0.5
      ),
      sliderInput(
        inputId = "freq",
        label = "Freq:",
        min = 0.1,
        max = 10,
        value = 0.5
      )
    ),

    # Show a plot
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot")
    )
  )
)

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    amp <- input$amp
    freq <- input$freq

    curve(amp * sin(freq * x), xlim = c(0, 10), ylim = c(-1, 1))
  })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks. But for some reason, the latency is so slow (even it's on localhost and very powerful computer with 8 cores), that it is even slower than the previous solution with releasing mouse button...